# MVC where to put validation that requires a db call

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, domain-driven-design

Take this simple, common scenario in an mvc app:

When a user registers the username needs to be unique.

Now I've read lot about project structure, domain-driven design, validation, mvc etc and I'm happy about my logical layers: Domain (Model, Core), Domain Services, Controllers and Views. I can ensure e.g. the username is less than 10 characters by adding a validation attribute to my property. Failures will bubble up back through the service layer into the controller and out into the view.

But for this simple scenario I am stuck as to the best solution for the call stack - and have that tested well, since this validation needs to call the db to check all other usernames.

For me, this is still a validation concern of the User model. I would really like to be able to create a custom validation attribute, so that when this property is set, persistence is checked to ensure uniqueness.

Woah there! A domain object calling the db directly?? I'm not sure its a bad thing. I can have castle inject IRespositories into the Domain, right, so no tight coupling and after all its the Domain that defines the data interfaces.

Does anyone have any experience/ opinions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've stuck to my gut feeling that this type of behaviour should be handled in the Domain, and it seems I am not alone.

The recent builds of S#arp Architecture have included a new Class Validation attribute HasUniqueDomainSignature, used in conjunction with Property attribute DomainSignature. When calling IsValid on NHibernate.Vaidator, the Common Service Locator is used to locate the current NHibernate session and persistence is referenced.

[Here's](http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture/browse_thread/thread/9789b34ac1bbf5fb) a discussion on it.

Answer (score 0):

> For me, this is still a validation concern of the User model.

Wrong... It surely isn't. User shouldn't know about siblings.

If User is entity (which it quite surely isn't), validating uniqueness is responsibility of containing aggregate root.

If it's an aggregate root, then there isn't much options (because "nothing holds" an aggregate root, they are global) - I use repositories for that despite that they shouldn't have domain logic. but then again - I do not consider this kind of uniqueness validation as [really valuable](http://gojko.net/2010/06/11/udi-dahan-the-biggest-mistakes-teams-make-when-applying-ddd/) (see "All rules aren’t created equal").

Answer (score -1):

If you are going DDD route perhaps you should consider using Commands for initiating domain changes. Then domain objects won't need to have validation on them: you may do all the required validation on command.

As for attribute-based validation, which some frameworks provide (like asp.net mvc), I really hate that. Your domain model shouldn't be their concern. The domain objects should always be in valid state, and maintain their invariants themselves.

Comment: i beg to differ. validation should be described along with my property declarations. i'd go, and have even further and sugggest this be used to generate your database schema, so that this definition is master and is only ever described in one place. i really do not like to see validation in a service method as someone could create a new service method later on that does something similar but fails to add the validation. dangerous.

Comment: @BobTodd you are talking more of a data-driven app rather than domain-driven here. In DDD, you shouldn't be setting properties on your entities(at which time they validate). You should manipulate your entity via public methods, which ensure the entity is valid all the time. No need for validation attributes there. And as someone mentioned, ensuring uniquiness constraints should be responsibility of containing AR.

Comment: actually i was more thinking on the lines, before a DAO commits a DO, it calls IsValid() on the DO, which infers the rules by reflection from these attributes. Its just a clean aspected way of specifying validation rules. I can set the username using the constructor (whether its yet valid or not). The controller checks whether the instance is valid, if not it messages to the user. This is DDD - logic in the domain, not an anemic model where the logic lives outside of the domain. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_Domain_Model